# Why aren't firstResult and maxResult working in withCriteria?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm getting the following error:

> Class
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
>   Message
>   No signature of method: com.apposit.terra.connect.service.OrganizationUserService.firstResult() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [2] Possible solutions: findResult(groovy.lang.Closure), findResult(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure)
>   Around line 35 of grails-app/services/com/apposit/terra/connect/service/OrganizationUserService.groovy

```
32:     if(null != organization)
33:                return User.withCriteria { eq( "organization" , organization)
34:                                           eq( "accountExpired" , false )
35:                                                firstResult( offset )
36:                                                maxResults( max )
37:
38:                                       }
```

I'm using mongodb.

Comment: Hey, has this been solved yet? I'm having the same problem. I tried to convert `offset` to `int`, `Integer`, `String`, etc. but the same error message occur.

Comment: @Gideon No I didn't :( maybe we should set some bounty on the question or something...

Comment: I've [asked separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532819/including-the-max-and-offset-criteria-inside-gorm-criteriabuilder-returns-an-err) already just a while ago, though I already received [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31533157/4043409).

Comment: @Gideon I can see... Are you using mongodb like I do?

Comment: No. I'm using OracleDB, though I think the problem doesn't lie on the database.

Comment: switch firstResult and maxResults to params for the withCriteria method:
withCriteria (offset: offset, max : max){...} Not entirely sure why, but I think it has to do with either the Grails, Groovy, and/or NHibernate version.