# Including the max and offset criteria inside GORM criteriaBuilder returns an error

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

Can I make this code shorter?

```
if(count == null && from = null) {
    creditAdviceList = CreditAdvice.findAll {
        ilike('id', "%$idFilter%")
        .....
        ilike('statusCode', statusCodeFilter)
    }
}
else if(count != null && from == null) {
    creditAdviceList = CreditAdvice.findAll(max: count) {
        ilike('id', "%$idFilter%")
        .....
        ilike('statusCode', statusCodeFilter)
    }
}
else if(count == null && from != null) {
    creditAdviceList = CreditAdvice.findAll(offset: from) {
        ilike('id', "%$idFilter%")
        .....
        ilike('statusCode', statusCodeFilter)
    }
}
else if(count != null && from != null) {
    creditAdviceList = CreditAdvice.findAll(max: count, offset: from) {
        ilike('id', "%$idFilter%")
        .....
        ilike('statusCode', statusCodeFilter)
    }
}
```

You see, its a series `if` statement for each possible scenario. Imagine if one would to use also `order` and `cache` in the parameter- there will be basically 16 unique `if` statements!

I've tried this [more] shorter code:

```
creditAdviceList = CreditAdvice.findAll {
    ilike('id', "%$idFilter%")
    .....
    ilike('statusCode', statusCodeFilter)

    if(count != null) {
        maxResults(count)
    }
    if(from != null) {
        firstResult(from)
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error:

> `...No signature of method: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.maxResults() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer)...`

I tried to convert `offset` to `int`, `Integer`, `String`, etc. I also omit the `if` statement inside the criteria, but the same error message occur.

Comment: The second version can work, you just need replace "findAll {...}" by "createCriteria().list {...}" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll` with a closure passed is using a `DetachedCriteria` internally, which is not the same as the result you would get from `createCriteria` mentioned in the docs.  If groovy would find "something close" enough, it would tell you in the error message.  The easiest way to deal with your max/from demands would be with simply with a map (which is the first argument passed).  E.g.:

```
def qcfg = [:]
if (count) {
    qcfg.count = count
}
if (from) {
    qcfg.offset = from
}
creditAdviceList = CreditAdvice.findAll(qcfg) { ... }
```

mix, match, extract, shorten as you see fit

Comment: IDEs shouldn't have copy-and-paste buttons ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the only difference is the pagination options. If my eyes are not tricking me, yes, you can:

```
Map paginationArgs = [max: count, offset: from].findAll { 
   it.value != null 
}
List<CreditAdvice> creditAdviceList = CreditAdvice.findAll(paginationArgs) {
   ilike('id', "%$idFilter%")
   .....
   ilike('statusCode', statusCodeFilter)
}
```

You can style it differently, but basically you can build the pagination arguments first, and pass them to the `findAll`. No duplicated code, clearer responsability of the conditions. To clarify, I'm adding all the options and then filtering them to exclude the ones that are null.